# How to rename all columns, cast data types based on the schema / read from csv file after creating the dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Created the sample dataframe  in pyspark

```
   from pyspark.sql.types import *
   from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
   from pyspark.sql import types
   testdata = [("aaaa",1,50.0,"05-APR-2020"),
               ("bbbb",2,100.0,"06-APR-2020")]
   dataschema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('col1', types.StringType(), True),
        types.StructField('col2', types.IntegerType(), True),
        types.StructField('col3', types.DoubleType(), True),
        types.StructField('col4', types.DateType(), True)
    ])
   testdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(
          spark.sparkContext.parallelize(testdata),
          dataschema
          )
   testdf2.printSchema()
   testdf2.show()
```

Getting the following error.

TypeError: field col4: DateType can not accept object '05-APR-2020' in type

If i have a list with 2 columns one is with new column and other with data type. 
How can i rename all columns and cast data type of each column based on the list or csv/json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spark doesn't convert **string** to **`date type`**.

We need to use **`datetime`** module to define our input data then while reading with schema spark creates `col4` to datetype.

**`Example:`**

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql import types
testdata = [("aaaa",1,50.0,datetime.datetime.strptime('05-APR-2020','%d-%b-%Y')),
            ("bbbb",2,100.0,datetime.datetime.strptime('06-APR-2020','%d-%b-%Y'))]

dataschema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('col1', types.StringType(), True),
        types.StructField('col2', types.IntegerType(), True),
        types.StructField('col3', types.DoubleType(), True),
        types.StructField('col4', types.DateType(), True)
    ])

testdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(
          spark.sparkContext.parallelize(testdata),
          dataschema
          )
testdf2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
# |-- col4: date (nullable = true)


testdf2.show()
#+----+----+-----+----------+
#|col1|col2| col3|      col4|
#+----+----+-----+----------+
#|aaaa|   1| 50.0|2020-04-05|
#|bbbb|   2|100.0|2020-04-06|
#+----+----+-----+----------+
```

---

Other way is by defining **`stringtype`** for `col4` then converting to `date` using `to_date`function.

```
dataschema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('col1', types.StringType(), True),
        types.StructField('col2', types.IntegerType(), True),
        types.StructField('col3', types.DoubleType(), True),
        types.StructField('col4', types.StringType(), True)
    ])

testdata = [("aaaa",1,50.0,"05-APR-2020"),
               ("bbbb",2,100.0,"06-APR-2020")]

spark.createDataFrame(testdata,dataschema).withColumn("col4",to_date(col("col4"),"dd-MMM-yyyy")).printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
# |-- col4: date (nullable = true)

spark.createDataFrame(testdata,dataschema).withColumn("col4",to_date(col("col4"),"dd-MMM-yyyy")).show()
#+----+----+-----+----------+
#|col1|col2| col3|      col4|
#+----+----+-----+----------+
#|aaaa|   1| 50.0|2020-04-05|
#|bbbb|   2|100.0|2020-04-06|
#+----+----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine. I have metadata from csv/json file with column , data type any conversion logic required for date/timestamp( format). Can we create  the dataframe with columns which are there in file and apply casting dynamically.